# Using of 2 for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I want to get information from user, and show it with for loop. I wrote this code:

```
name=["Name","Age","Gender"]
n=str(input())
a=int(input())
g=str(input())
nameinput=[n,a,g]
for i in name:
    for j in nameinput:
        print(i,j)
```

I expect the output of code to be:

> Name Fuad, Age 18, Gender M

but the actual output is

> Name Fuad Name 18 Name M Age Fuad Age 18 Age M Gender Fuad Gender 18
>   Gender M

How I can fix this problem and please can you explain why my code isn't running

Comment: The inner loop runs fully for every one iteration of the outer loop. They don't run 1:1

Answer (score 5):

You are doing nested loops which iterates the cartesian product (every element of `name` is paired with every element of `nameinput`). You want to do *pair-wise* iteration of multiple iterables, which is achieved by [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for i, j in zip(name, nameinput):
    print(i,j)
```

The workings of `zip` can be illustrated by the following example:

```
list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
# [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Nested loops, however, would do:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i in [1, 2, 3] for j in [4, 5, 6]]
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

If you think through your loop code step-by-step, that logic should become clear.